# Excel or Google Sheets—Is there a way to duplicate rows in place using only formulas?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, lambda, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

Using only excel/google sheets formulas, I would like to take a table like this:

```
a b c
q r s
x y z
```

and turn it into something like this:

```
a b c
a b c
a b c
q r s
q r s
q r s
x y z
x y z
x y z
```

The point is that the rows are duplicated n times but maintain the sort order of the original table.

Comment: Asking for both is too broad.  Please choose one and please include what you have tried.

Comment: Alternatively: `=MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(A:A)*3,3,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(A:C,ROUNDUP(r/3),c)))`

Comment: I completely agree with the close decision except that the previous answers were Google sheets only, for 1D arrays not 2D arrays, and didn't include any Lambdas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in google sheets:

```
=LAMBDA(y, z, INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(TEXT(BYROW(y, LAMBDA(x, 
 TEXTJOIN("​",,x))), IFERROR(SEQUENCE(1, z)/0, "@"))), "​")))
 (A1:C3, 3)
```

[image: =LAMBDA(x;y;MAKEARRAY(ROWS(x)*y;COLUMNS(X);LAMBDA(r;c;INDEX(x;ROUNDUP(r/y);c))))(A1:C3;3)=MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(A:A)*3,3,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(A:C,ROUNDUP(r/3),c)))]

or try:

```
=LAMBDA(x, y, REDUCE(x, SEQUENCE(y-1), 
 LAMBDA(a, b, IF(b, {a; x}))))
 (A1:C3, 3)
```

Comment: Man you're getting better with `REDUCE`, could you be more slower?O.O

Comment: Wow—thank you so much! The top suggestion preserves the order the way I wanted . The shorter lambda function did duplicate the rows, but didn't group the same ones together.

Comment: With 0 as the jersey number :D @player0

Comment: I really like the nesting with `REDUCE()` in `LAMBDA()`. I did try this and it's not stacking correctly. I used `=LAMBDA(x;y;MAKEARRAY(ROWS(x)*y;COLUMNS(X);LAMBDA(r;c;INDEX(x;ROUNDUP(r/y);c))))(A1:C3;3)` to fix that but it's essentially the same technique. Well done! Good alternative to the missing `LET()` function.

Comment: @JvdV Your function allows blank cells to be included in the data being duplicated, which is nice. Thanks for the comment!