# Repeat each value a different number of times, in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, repeat

Given a list of values and a number `n` *for each value*, is there a way to create a 1-dimensional list with each value repeating `n` times?

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **animal** | **# repeats** | **result** |
| **2** | aardvark | 3 | aardvark |
| **3** | badger | 0 | aardvark |
| **4** | capybara | 1 | aardvark |
| **5** | duck | 2 | capybara |
| **6** |  |  | duck |
| **7** |  |  | duck |

Ideally, this would be a single formula in C2.

I'm working in Google Sheets, but I'd be interested in Excel answers, too.

Note that *this is different from [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55481291/repeat-each-row-n-times-in-google-sheets)* [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74146911/excel-or-google-sheets-is-there-a-way-to-duplicate-rows-in-place-using-only-form) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54266412/repeat-range-of-items-multiple-times-in-google-sheets), which have the same `n` for all values.

Comment: @player0, this is similar to 55481291, but not the same, as I pointed out. I only posted this question after I was unable to make your answer and the others from that question work for my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try either

```
=TOCOL(MAP(A2:A,B2:B,LAMBDA(a,b,WRAPROWS(a,b,a))),3)
```

OR

```
=LAMBDA(z,FILTER(z,z<>""))(FLATTEN(MAP(A2:A,B2:B,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(a="",,IFERROR(SPLIT(REPT(a&"|",b),"|")))))))
```

- 

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Repeat Rows a Given Number of Times (Excel Formula)

- Due to the poor performance of the `XLOOKUP` or `XMATCH` functions (23s on 10k rows), the superior `MATCH` function is used with the `INDEX` function (3s on 10k rows).

**LET**

```
=LET(Data,A2:A5,Repeats,B2:B5,
    Both,HSTACK(Data,Repeats),Filtered,FILTER(Both,Repeats>0),
    dData,TAKE(Filtered,,1),dStacked,VSTACK(dData,""),
    rData,TAKE(Filtered,,-1),rSequence,SEQUENCE(SUM(rData)),
    rStacked,VSTACK(0,rData),rScanned,SCAN(1,rStacked,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b)),
    rIndexes,MATCH(rSequence,rScanned),
Result,INDEX(dStacked,rIndexes),Result)
```

If you prefer fewer variables:

```
=LET(Data,A2:A5,Repeats,B2:B5,
    Filtered,FILTER(HSTACK(Data,Repeats),Repeats>0),
    dStacked,VSTACK(TAKE(Filtered,,1),""),
    rData,TAKE(Filtered,,-1),rSequence,SEQUENCE(SUM(rData)),
    rScanned,SCAN(1,VSTACK(0,rData),LAMBDA(a,b,a+b)),
Result,INDEX(dStacked,MATCH(rSequence,rScanned)),Result)
```

[image]

**Screenshot Formulas**

```
F2  =HSTACK(A2:A5,B2:B5)
H2  =FILTER(F3#,B2:B5>0)
J2  =TAKE(H3#,,1)
K2  =VSTACK(J3#,"")
L2  =TAKE(H3#,,-1)
M2  =SEQUENCE(SUM(L3#))
N2  =VSTACK(0,L3:L5)
O2  =SCAN(1,N3#,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))
P2  =MATCH(M3#,O3#)
Q2  =INDEX(K3#,P3#)
R2  =LAMBDA(Data,Repeats,LET(
        Both,HSTACK(Data,Repeats),Filtered,FILTER(Both,Repeats>0),
        dData,TAKE(Filtered,,1),dStacked,VSTACK(dData,""),
        rData,TAKE(Filtered,,-1),rSequence,SEQUENCE(SUM(rData)),
        rStacked,VSTACK(0,rData),rScanned,SCAN(1,rStacked,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b)),
        rIndexes,MATCH(rSequence,rScanned),
    Result,INDEX(dStacked,rIndexes),Result))(A2:A5,B2:B5)
S2  =LAMBDA(Data,Repeats,LET(
        Both,HSTACK(Data,Repeats),Filtered,FILTER(Both,Repeats>0),
        dData,TAKE(Filtered,,1),dStacked,VSTACK(dData,""),
        rData,TAKE(Filtered,,-1),rSequence,SEQUENCE(SUM(rData)),
        rStacked,VSTACK(0,rData),rScanned,SCAN(1,rStacked,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b)),
        rIndexes,MATCH(rSequence,rScanned),
    Result,INDEX(dStacked,rIndexes),Result))
```

Using the last formula, define a name e.g. `RepeatSeq`, and use the name instead:

```
=RepeatSeq(A2:A5,B2:B5)
```

Answer (score 1):

pretty much the same:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(
 REPT(A2:A10&"♠", B2:B10), ,9^9), "♠"))))
```

[image]