# Repeat each value a different number of times. Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sequence, powerquery

There are 2 columns of data:

```
a 2
b 3
c 1
```

Result:

```
X01a
X02a
X01b
X02b
X03b
X01c
```

In Google Sheets I use the formula:

```
=tocol(map(A2:A;B2:B;lambda(a;b;if(counta({a\b})<>2;;index("X"&text(sequence(1;b);"00")&a&"|"&b))));1)
```

In Excel this formula gives an error: #CALC! error (Nested Array)

How to do this in Excel?

Found answer in [Repeat each value a different number of times, in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75339673/repeat-each-value-a-different-number-of-times-in-google-sheets)

I don’t understand how to adapt this formula for my purposes.

```
=LET(Data,A2:A5,Repeats,B2:B5,
    Both,HSTACK(Data,Repeats),Filtered,FILTER(Both,Repeats>0),
    dData,TAKE(Filtered,,1),dStacked,VSTACK(dData,""),
    rData,TAKE(Filtered,,-1),rSequence,SEQUENCE(SUM(rData)),
    rStacked,VSTACK(0,rData),rScanned,SCAN(1,rStacked,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b)),
    rIndexes,MATCH(rSequence,rScanned),
Result,INDEX(dStacked,rIndexes),Result)
```

The formula will return over 250k results. I wish it didn't hang up. :)

Found the answer using an extra column. [Is there a non-VBA Excel spilling formula to create and process arrays of arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74181973/is-there-a-non-vba-excel-spilling-formula-to-create-and-process-arrays-of-arrays)

How to get the result without an extra column?
All suggested methods return:

```
a
a
b
b
b
c
```

I need a result with running numbers.

```
1a
2a
1b
2b
3b
1c
```

Comment: There is a typo in the present edit it should be `1a`, `2a`, `1b`, `2b`, `3b`, & `1c` and not `3c`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya 
Haven't tried it yet. I think your formula is correct. I'll get to the computer tomorrow morning and try it. Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following formula using <kbd>MAKEARRAY()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, A1:A3,
     φ, B1:B3,
     TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(ROWS(α),MAX(φ),LAMBDA(δ,ε,
     IF(ε<=INDEX(φ,δ),TEXT(ε,"X00")&INDEX(α,δ),p))),3))
```

---

Alternative approach, but note due to the use of <kbd>ARRAYTOTEXT()</kbd> there are character limitations:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=TEXTSPLIT(ARRAYTOTEXT(MAP(A1:A3,B1:B3,LAMBDA(α,φ,ARRAYTOTEXT(TEXT(SEQUENCE(,φ),"X00")&α)))),,", ")
```

---

Also in the given link there was indeed a solution using helper columns but it could have been accomplished with some fine tunning of the formula proposed by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=DROP(REDUCE("",A1:A3&"|"&B1:B3,LAMBDA(a,b,
  LET(x,TEXTBEFORE(b,"|"),y,--TEXTAFTER(b,"|"),
  VSTACK(a,TEXT(SEQUENCE(y),"X00")&INDEX(x,SEQUENCE(y,,,0)))))),1)
```

---

Reference Link to post: **[Is there a non-VBA Excel spilling formula to create and process arrays of arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74181973/is-there-a-non-vba-excel-spilling-formula-to-create-and-process-arrays-of-arrays)**

---

This can be accomplished quickly and easily using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>. To achieve this using the said procedure, follow this simple steps using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd> window `UI`:

---

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Create_Sequence = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each {1..[Column2]}),
    Expand_To_NewRows = Table.ExpandListColumn(Create_Sequence, "Custom"),
    Padding = Table.AddColumn(Expand_To_NewRows, "Output", each "X" & Text.PadStart(Text.From([Custom]),2,"0") & [Column1]),
    Remove_Unwanted_Cols = Table.SelectColumns(Padding,{"Output"}),
    Removed_Empty = Table.SelectRows(Remove_Unwanted_Cols, each [Output] <> null and [Output] <> "")
in
    Removed_Empty
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

[image]

---